# How can I calculate a running average in parallel with R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using Windows 8 and would appreciate solutions that do not require Linux.

My actual problem is much more complex, but if this can work, then my problem will be solved. Since the jobs are being split into different cores, all of the "previous" calculations are not available in every iteration. Here is my attempt:

```
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)
cl <- makeCluster(3, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)
avg_x <- 0

foo <- foreach(i=1:10, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  x <- rnorm(1, 0, 1)
  if (i == 1) avg_x <- x
  if (i > 1) avg_x <- (avg_x*(i-1) + x) / i
  return(list(index=i, 
              x=x, 
              avg_x=avg_x))
}
stopCluster(cl)
foo <- as.data.frame(foo)
foo$real_avg <- cumsum(foo$x)/(1:10)
```

Here is the output:

```
> foo
          index           x      avg_x    real_avg
result.1      1   0.5794659  0.5794659  0.57946591
result.2      2   -0.425142  -0.212571  0.07716198
result.3      3  -0.7871111 -0.2623704 -0.21092906
result.4      4   0.7277492  0.6165367  0.02374051
result.5      5   -1.236796 -0.4174159 -0.22836676
result.6      6  -0.4746637    0.43467 -0.26941625
result.7      7    1.121336 -0.1975943 -0.07073741
result.8      8 0.007783448  0.3813092 -0.06092231
result.9      9   -1.218424 -0.3110198 -0.18953361
result.10    10   0.3948681  0.3826651 -0.13109344
```

If it isn't possible to calculate the running average for every iteration, would it be possible to somehow calculate it after every 3 iterations?

Update:
I had an idea on how to do this which I think will work but I cannot seem to get it programmed properly. The idea is to update a data.frame within foreach. 3 out of 4 of the workers will be generating random numbers and the other one will be calculating the running average using the previous iterations. I am getting an error trying to update the data.frame though.

```
library(snow)
library(doSNOW)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster(4, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cl)

f <- data.frame(x=rep(0,13), 
                ind=rep(0,13), 
                runAvg=rep(0,13))

foreach(i=icount(13), .export='f') %dopar% {
  if (i == 1) return
  if ((i-1)%%4 != 0) {
    #cores 2, 3, 4 just get populated with the random numbers
    f[i,] <- c(rnorm(1, 0, 1), i, 0)
  }
  if ((i-1)%%4 == 0){
    #core 1 only calculates the running average
    f[i,] <- (f[i-4,3]*(i - 4 - (i+3)/4)) + (f[i-3,1] + f[i-2,1] + f[i-1,1])/(i - (i+3/4))
  }
}
stopCluster(cl)
f
```

In the end I am getting an error and the data.frame f has not changed at all. Here is the error I am getting:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "replacement has 0 items, need 3"
In addition: Warning message:
In e$fun(obj, substitute(ex), parent.frame(), e$data) :
  already exporting variable(s): f
```

Comment: I do not see how running average can be paralleled: for index `i` it depends on `x[i]` and `av[i-1]`. Do you have an idea how it can be possible?

Comment: @tonytonov I just updated the question with a little more of an idea of how I thought it could be done.

Comment: What is the outcome you're looking for? Just a `data.table` with a row-by-row cumulative average of all the rows above it? If so, you can just calculate this after the fact. You cannot have each parallel process editing an object in its parent environment. You would end up with clashes - one process might finishe while another has locked the object because it's already editing the global variable, blocking the second process. Anyway, to do post-processing of the result within the `foreach` function call, use the `.final` argument.